# Set a custom resolution in windows

Tags: drivers, resolution, graphics

My PC sticks to 1024x768 resolution that creates a stretched/distorted screen regardless of the monitor connected to it. My requirement is FHD (1080p) and I've no idea how to change it. Thanks in advance.
What we know for sure / What I've tried already:

- It's a brand new 11th gen PC (no GPU) with no drivers or software installed.
- Connecting to a different monitor, but the PC recognizes every monitor as "PNP Monitor" and sticks to the default resolution
- Upgrading to windows 11 hasn't changed anything
- I've tried the common fixes from google
- Trying "list all options" only displays options less than the resolution
- I tried installing the intel graphics driver and changing the resolution through that, but it just says "Bad parameters", when I enter 1920x1080
- Neither does gigabyte H510 motherboard's drivers have solved the issue
- I don't want to install third-party software on my PC
- I'm comfortable working with the command line
- The problem is definitely in the graphics driver.
- I use an LG 24MK600M monitor and haven't found any drivers that came with it

Comment: What make and model is your monitor? What display connection are you using?

Comment: @Daniel B I am using an LG 24MK600M monitor and the only display port on my motherboard is VGA , so yeah that's what I am using

Comment: That’s not correct. According to Gigabyte, your mainboard has a HDMI output.

Comment: Hey this one specifically, which doesn't have a HDMI:https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/H510M-S2-rev-10#kf

Comment: These are things you check before buying…. I noticed that there are multiple H510 models by Gigabyte. Please provide the exact model number. // Update: I recommend you return this mainboard, if you can. Otherwise, you might want to consider getting a cheap office graphics card. VGA is dead.

Comment: Good grief… I'd send the display back too; aside from the fact it's VGA-only, which makes it at least a decade out of date, its colour spec is appalling  - Color Gamut (CIE1931) NTSC 72% - that's barely adequate for word processing, let alone looking at images:\

Comment: Yeah, I had looked at the NTSC but was in hurry so bought the monitor. But unfortunately I can't return either of these : (

Comment: Thank you for replying.. Getting a graphics card could be the only option left